# Обработка каждого числа из диапазона в случайном порядке

Tags: c, алгоритм

Имеется два числа задающих диапазон, нужно в цикле что-то сделать с каждым числом но не по порядку циклом, а в случайном порядке.
Диапазоны заведомо не известны и являются большими поэтому сложность и потребление памяти нужны O(1).
Какие алгоритмы/паттерны для этого можно использовать?

Comment: Уточните, насколько случайным должен быть случайный порядок? Нужна ли истинная случайность, псевдо, или может даже простой перебор с шагом сгодится?

Comment: Какой-то истинной случайности точно не нужно, можете себе представить что диапазон разделен на блоки разного неизвестного мне размера(известно разве что максимум чисел которые может вместить блок) и вот мне надо как можно реже обрабатывать число из каждого блока. Возможно и какой либо шаг сгодится даже но разумеется не статичный.

Comment: используйте "алгоритм Иосифа".  Выбирается какое то число, желательно, что бы НОД(число, размер массива) было 1. а дальше следующий индекст это предыдущий + число и делить по модулю на размер массива.

Comment: Можете написать примерную реализацию, а то я не особо понял как это реализовать? Хотел бы так же уточнить на всякий случай что массивов у меня нет, то есть число != индекс в массиве например, для меня нужная информация в числе.

Comment: А где и как у вас лежат эти числа?

Comment: `struct { uint32_t start; uint32_t end; };`

Comment: Интересная задачка. А постоянный (в принципе его можно сделать случайным для каждого перебора) шаг Вам точно не годится? Также довольно легко можно сделать, что сначала выдается первое число каждого блока, потом второе и т.д.

Comment: Насчет постоянного шага честно я не знаю, если при постоянном шаге будет выполнятся основная задача которую я описал в комментарии выше то безусловно метод сгодится.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Набросал код, беглые тесты показывают, что он вроде решает Вашу задачу.
код написан на с99 (то есть, используется объявление переменных не в начале блока), поэтому в gcc нужно компилировать с `-std=c99`, студия 2013 может не скомпилировать, а 2015 скорее всего справиться. Но переписать код не проблема, что бы он работал даже с древними компиляторами.

Потребление памяти тут точно `O(1)`, так как память выделяется только под всякие локальные переменные, никаких массивов и скрытых рекурсий.

Самая сложная часть - это поиск шага. Данный алгоритм пытается найти минимальный шаг. Но в теории там сложность `O(n)`. Данный алгоритм в лоб ищет первое нечетное взаимопростое с длинной число. Данную часть можно дорабатывать до получения нужных значений.

Если посмотреть визуализацию заполнения, то это будет выглядеть так. Весь диапазон будет поделен на группы по step и step-1 элементов и вначале будет заполнен каждый первый элемент в группах, потом каждый второй и так далее. То есть, порядок не случайный, но достаточно размазаный. Если же хочется немного большей случайности, то следует посмотреть на [Линейный конгруэнтный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4) глубже и научиться генерировать для него коэффициенты.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* нод, взято с википедии */

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    while (b != 0)
    {
        int r = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
    return a;
}

/* что то сделать с i */
void doit(int i)
{
    printf("do with %i\n", i);
}

/* включая a и не включая b, то есть [a,b) */
void processrange(int a, int b)
{
    int len = b - a;
    if (len <= 0) {
        return; /* диапазон вырожден*/
    }
    /* поищем хороший шаг */
  /* если такое случиться, что шаг не будет найден, то будет 1 */
    int step = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i < len/2; i+=2) {
        if (gcd(i, len) == 1) {
            step = i;
            break;
        }
    }
  /* собственно цикл */
    int ind = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        doit(a + ind);
        ind = (ind + step) % len;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    processrange(100,200);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В принципе можно добавить случайность в выбор шага (искать нод от `rand() % (len/2) + 1` до 1). Я спрашивал ТС в комментарии о таком подходе, но он что-то молчит. По хорошему, тут надо бы придумать какую-то формулу для переменного шага, обеспечивающую однократное посещение всех чисел, но у меня не получается.

Comment: Не знаю как в теории но на практике О(n) не заметно, если вы конечно имели в ввиду время между вызовом фунции `doit`. Оно у меня одинаковое и при диапазоне 1-1000000 и при 1-1000000000. Алгоритм отлично подходит.

Comment: просто алгоритм очень быстро находит подходящий шаг.

Comment: Да, уже понял, в вычислении шага О(n) но оно роли не играет ибо действительно происходит очень быстро